# Trap Alt-F4 in QB64

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

I have a utility that has a function called by Alt-F4 but I can't because it closes the window. How can I trap Alt-F4 in QB64?

The following code samples shows various ways to check for Alt-F4:

```
REM Trap Alt-F4 in QB64
DO
    _LIMIT 100
    x$ = INKEY$
    IF x$ = CHR$(27) THEN END
    IF LEN(x$) = 2 THEN
        IF ASC(RIGHT$(x$, 1)) = 107 THEN
            PRINT "Alt-F4"
        END IF
    END IF
LOOP
END
```

Also tried this with no effect:

```
KEY 15, CHR$(8) + CHR$(62)
ON KEY(15) GOSUB KeyTrap
KEY(15) ON
DO
    _LIMIT 100
    x$ = INKEY$
    IF x$ = CHR$(27) THEN END
LOOP
END
KeyTrap:
PRINT "Alt-F4"
RETURN
```

Also tried to trap Alt-F4 in _EXIT trap with no results:

```
' start timer trap.
ON TIMER(1) GOSUB Timer.Trap
TIMER ON
VarQ = _EXIT
DO
    _LIMIT 100
LOOP
END
' timer ctrl-break trap.
Timer.Trap:
VarQ = _EXIT
_DELAY 1
IF VarQ THEN ' Control-Break
    x$ = INKEY$
    IF LEN(x$) = 2 THEN
        IF ASC(RIGHT$(x$, 1)) = 107 THEN
            PRINT "Alt-F4"
            RETURN
        END IF
    END IF
    CLS
    SYSTEM
END IF
RETURN
```

Another possible way to trap Alt-F4:

Only this checks more keyhits.

```
CONST KEY_RALT& = 100307
CONST KEY_LALT& = 100308
' start timer trap.
ON TIMER(1) GOSUB Timer.Trap
TIMER ON
VarQ = _EXIT
DO
    _LIMIT 100
LOOP
END
' timer ctrl-break trap.
Timer.Trap:
VarQ = _EXIT
_DELAY 1
IF VarQ THEN ' Control-Break
    x = _KEYHIT
    IF x = CVI(CHR$(0) + CHR$(62)) THEN ' F4
        IF _KEYDOWN(KEY_RALT&) OR _KEYDOWN(KEY_LALT&) THEN
            PRINT "Alt-F4"
            RETURN
        END IF
    END IF
    CLS
    SYSTEM
END IF
RETURN
```

Also have a sample code for checking using memory addresses:

As well, it does not either trap Alt-F4:

```
DO
    _LIMIT 30
    b$ = INKEY$
    IF LEN(b$) THEN
        IF b$ = CHR$(27) THEN END
        DEF SEG = 0
        IF PEEK(1047) MOD 16 = 8 THEN
            IF b$ = CHR$(0) + "k" THEN
                PRINT "Alt-F4"
            END IF
        END IF
        DEF SEG
    END IF
LOOP
```

Comment: The behavior of Alt-F4 is controlled by Windows. One suggestion I found was to [remove the `Close` option from the window's system menu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100604-00/?p=13803) (see the first `DisableCloseButton` function; `hwnd` in your case will be replaced by `GetForegroundWindow()`). As an aside, the `PEEK` solution won't work because QB64's 16-bit memory is emulated, meaning you're reading memory, not hardware state. Of course, even if it worked, you still need to read that before the window message loop processes the key press (because multithreading).

Comment: MSDN says that only enables/disables Close/Minimized/Maximized. I don't want to change those, only tell QB64 not to trap Alt-F4.

Comment: In that case, you might be able to trap a single message like `WM_KEYDOWN`; that would, in theory, appear before `WM_SYSCOMMAND`, allowing you to filter that key press, so the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message is never passed with `SC_CLOSE` via Alt-F4. A similar option to trapping the keypress might be `RegisterHotKey`. I've never needed this particular functionality, however, so I can't say for certain how much C code this requires, if any, or even whether you need to start your own thread for a new message loop or something, just to trap a key press.

Comment: It seems QB64 traps Alt-F4 in libqb.cpp and is hardcoded. I am working with the QB64 crew to establish a _EXITKEY override function right now.

Comment: Why must it be alt-F4?  As a software developer, you should code for your potential users' needs, and I don't think the typical user would be happy with an application that hi-jacked a Windows shortcut key.  The quickest, and best (in my 35+ years experience as a developer) suggestion is to pick another shortcut key.  How about Esc :)

Comment: Because 1)after porting it from 16-bit DOS (which had no "windows" in cmd) to 32-bit QB64 (which does), I wanted it to be backwards compatible.. and 2)i am using all the possible keyboard scancodes available and have none leftover..

Comment: And I am not hi-jacking a Windows shortcut key - Windows hi-jacked my shortcut key and I want it back :)

Comment: I once (decades ago) didn't get a job because the legacy code I worked on used F1 as an escape key (abort) and the hiring manager said that everyone knows F1 is for help.  Yeah, I know, but my customers have been using F2 for help for a decade.  I'm just sympathizing is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is very simple:

#### Run in full screen.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or alter your program settings.  I forget what the chr$ codes for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is, but I'm pretty sure it was a `CHR$(0) + CHR$(x)` format.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alt-Enter has no effect on Alt-F4 they are both trapped by Windows

Comment: Did Alt+Enter put it in full screen?  It's been several years since I used Qbasic and I don't have a Windows install handy.  I'm nearly 100% positive I succeeded in capturing it, but I also know I always ran in full screen.  Also, it just struck me, I think I was using QB32.

Comment: What does Alt-Enter going to full screen have anything to do with Alt-F4 closing window?

Comment: With the version of Qbasic that I used, when the program was in full screen, Windows wouldn't capture as many key commands.  Alt+F4 would consequently be un-capturable by Windows, and I could capture it in Qbasic.  Alt+Enter is simply the key command (IIRC) to put Qbasic in full screen

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. It still makes no sense for my users to have to go to full screen to trap close windows though.